# How to handle typescript interfaces that are also used in mongoose

Tags: typescript

I'm using typescript with mongoose, everything works but now I want to use the type def in places that don't have the full reference, but only an id, for example, here are my models:

**IUser:**

```
export interface IUser {
    email: string,
    firstName: string,
    lastName: string,
}
```

**IWorkLog:**

```
export interface IWorkLog {
    author: IUser,
    body: string,
}
```

**WorkLogSchema:**

```
const WorkLogSchema: Schema = new Schema(
    {
        author: { type: String, ref: 'User', required: true },
        body: { type: String, required: true },
        timeSpent: String,
        timeSpentSeconds: Number
    }
);

const WorkLog = mongoose.model<IWorkLog>("WorkLog", WorkLogSchema);
export default WorkLog;
```

So far everything is normal (I think, I'm new to TS), now in a service, I'm getting some parameters to create the work log, and I want to tell it the type, but the author property I get is not the full object, just the id, so how can I tell typescript to use the proper definition?

```
    // the if I use IUser instead of 'any' here, it would expect a full 
    // user object, but my author property is just an id string, so how 
    // do I solve this issue?

    async create(args: any): Promise<WorkLog> {
        // ...create document
    }
```

Comment: `async create(args: string)`? What exactly isn't working?

Comment: It works but there is no type, u'd like to know how I can use a type here if what I get from the user for author is an id string, but the interface thinks its a full user object.